# Fieri potest with final ut or explicative quod

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, conjunction, subordinate-clause

Suppose I want to say:

> It can happen that my horse dies.

I do not want to say "my horse can die", but I want to keep this structure where the thing that happens is in a subordinate clause.
This helps clarify the structure in some longer sentences and it also gives a different tone.

"It can happen" is "Fieri potest", but I can think of two options for the rest:

> Fieri potest, ut equus meus moriatur.
> Fieri potest, quod equus meus moritur.

Are both of these valid?
If both are grammatical, is there a difference in tone?
Are there even more ways to form a similar subordinate clause?

I see the following difference between *ut* and *quod* (which I hope is clear enough from the more emphatic versions), but I am not sure if the Romans would agree:

> It can happen so that my horse dies.
> (Ita) fieri potest, ut equus meus moriatur.
>
> The thing can happen that my horse dies.
> (Id) fieri potest, quod equus meus moritur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never seen *fieri potest, quod*.

I find however several examples of *fieri potest, ut* subjunctive in the corpora; the first two are:

> Si hoc **fieri potest ut** in hac civitate quae longe iure libertatis ceteris civitatibus antecellit quisquam nullis comitiis imperium aut potestatem adsequi **possit**, quid attinet tertio capite legem curiatam ferre iubere, cum quarto permittas ut sine lege curiata idem iuris habeant quod haberent, si  optima lege a populo essent creati?
>   —Cicero, *De Lege Agraria*, 2.26.1
>
> Neque enim **fieri potest ut** aliud iudicari de iure, aliud responderi **oporteat**, nec **ut** quisquam iuris **numeretur** peritus qui id statuat esse ius quod non oporteat iudicari.
>   —Cicero, *Pro Cæcina*, 65.1

I myself don't mistake it for a purpose clause, especially since *si fieri potest* shows up a lot and seems to be a locution for "if possible," so I take it as a clue that what's coming up next isn't purpose. I'd mistake *quod*, though, for "because," and it would cause all kinds of confusion. (Not that that's unusual for me.)

Comment: This is yet another case where my intuition fights against Latin grammar, but I will have to accept attested classical guidelines. I hope my recent email with *fieri potest, quod* was understood without confusion...

Comment: Does it help at all to think of Greek ὡς?

Comment: Not really. I am such a barbarian that I don't know much about Greek syntax.